# Python using Groupby and Unpivot/pivot

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gzi1.png)  I am trying to count the number of project based for each stage. I want to have the columns be for the different stages, and the rows be for each month of every year we have. Right now I have all the data in a data-frame and i want to use the group-by tool to count the number of projects per month for every status, as mentioned before. If anyone needs further explanation I can answer questions.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwdt1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include sample data, sample code for your current approach, and the output you're getting vs the output you want. In order to help you, we need you to clearly state everything about the structure of the data and what you want it to look like when you're done

Comment: The numbers may not exactly match, but the main goal that I am trying to get across is the overall layout change from "Before" to "After"

Comment: nice thank you for adding that. That will help people. When possible it’s also good to try to include all of your information inside the post itself, not linked externally. This way if the link is ever broken other visitors still have access to the information

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you are looking for, so I made it real clear and if I didn't get what you meant let me know and I can easily fix it.

I think your dataframe looks something like this:

```
example_DF = pd.DataFrame({"stage_1":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 
                           "stage_2":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
example_DF.index.name = "month"
print(example_DF)
```

And if you want to get the sum of each stage over each month you just do this:

```
for stage in example_DF.columns:
    print("The stage is: ", status)
    for group_index, grouped_DF in example_DF.groupby([example_DF.index, stage]):
        print(grouped_DF)
```

but I'm confused because that is just every cell in the dataframe/you used stage and status. Let me know if I am missing something!

Comment: I have made some changes if you would like to check it out. Thanks!!